# EMULATOR 5554 offline Linux

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image]

Hello I have been trying to fix this issue.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your emulator is running.
You can try by restarting ADB.

Answer (score -1):

From [Android Debug Bridge (adb)](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html):

> Emulator not listed
>
> The adb devices command has a corner-case command sequence that causes
>   running emulator(s) to not show up in the adb devices output even
>   though the emulator(s) are visible on your desktop. This happens when
>   all of the following conditions are true:
>
> The adb server is not running, and
>          You use the emulator command with the -port or -ports option with an odd-numbered port value between 5554 and 5584, and
>          The odd-numbered port you chose is not busy so the port connection can be made at the specified port number, or if it is
>   busy, the emulator switches to another port that meets the
>   requirements in 2, and
>          You start the adb server after you start the emulator.

Other possibilities:

1. Your device is disconnected.
2. Bad/loose cable.
3. Device overheating or shutting off communication in power saving mode.  Some devices do this at screen off.
4. USB debugging is no longer enabled on your device.
5. Your computer's USB ports or OS control of them is not reliable (especially if you do alot of plugging/unplugging on the same port)
6. ADB has timed out waiting on your device to respond.

Try restarting ADB from terminal:  adb kill-server then adb devices